# How can I change this part of the code? The error is caused by the fact that I am trying to use it in C # 4 and as I understand it from C # 6

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change this part of the code? The error is caused by the fact that I am trying to use it in C # 4 and as I understand it from C # 6

Here is a soma bug!
Assets/Game/Lang/LocalizationManager.cs(22,35): error CS1644: Feature `auto-implemented property initializer' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Here!

```
public static EnLanguageEvent ChangeLanguage { get; set; } = new EnLanguageEvent();
```

She's coming here

```
private void SelectLanguage(EnLanguage _language)
    {
        laguage = _language;
        ChangeLanguage.Invoke(laguage);
    }
```

The entire script!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class LocalizationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum EnLanguage
    {
        RU,
        EN
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private EnLanguage laguage;

    [Space]
    public Button selectRu;
    public Button selectEn;

    public class EnLanguageEvent : UnityEvent<EnLanguage> { }

    public static EnLanguageEvent ChangeLanguage { get; set; } = new EnLanguageEvent();  // error is here

    private static LocalizationManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        selectRu.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectLanguage(EnLanguage.RU));
        selectEn.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectLanguage(EnLanguage.EN));
    }

    private void SelectLanguage(EnLanguage _language)
    {
        laguage = _language;
        ChangeLanguage.Invoke(laguage);
    }

    public static EnLanguage GetLanguage()
    {
        return instance.laguage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set it in the static constructor.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to be using C# 4.0?  It's 9 years old (Wikipedia shows it having been released in April 2010).

Comment: @Flydog57 Because Unity. If the asker is on an older version of Unity, he doesn't have a choice. And upgrading might not be feasible.

Comment: Just wanted to ask which Unity Version you are using and if migration to a newer Version is an option ^^

Comment: @derHugo 2018.2.15f When switching to a newer version of C #, the application on Android crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like you said, the problem is because you are using a newer feature (Auto-Implemented Property Initializer) that is not available at your target version of C#.

One way to solve this would be to add a backing field to your property and initialize the field instead:

```
private static EnLanguageEvent _changeLanguage = new EnLanguageEvent();

public static EnLanguageEvent ChangeLanguage
{
    get { return _changeLanguage; }
    set { _changeLanguage = value; }
}
```